# How is wait_for_completion different from wakeup_interruptible

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

How is wait_for_completion different from wakeup_interruptible?

Actually the question is how completion chains is different from wait queues ?
It looks the same concept to me

Answer (score 0):

completion structure internally uses the wait queues and locks.

completion structure was introduced to address a very common occurring scenario, where multiple threads are waiting on some event. Once that event happens, you want only one of the waiting thread to start running.

The key here is that kernel developers don't have to implement and maintain the waiting queue , which makes life of a kernel developer easy.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on Harman answer, I would also say that those two functions are called in different context: `wakeup_interruptible()` will **wake up** all threads waiting on a `wait_queue`, whereas `wait_for_completion()` will **wait** until a specific task completes. Those are two different things to me.